# How to use copula for multi-dimensional outputs regression?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, copula

It is well known that copula can be used to build the joint distribution of a set of random variables, ie. we can represent: 
$p(y_1;y_2;...y_p)= p(y_1) p(y_2)...p(y_p) c(F(y_1); F(y_2);..F(y_p)) $

Suppose we have to build a regression model that map an input $x \in R^d $ to an output $y \in R^p$. The output variables are correlated in some ways and can be described by, eg. copula model. We want to somehow exploit the correlation among outputs to improve the models (you want the model to predict well the future data based on  some error metrics). How to apply the strength of copula under this setting ?